# How to apply same operation on every block of block matrices in numpy efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big 2d array as following shape:

```
B = [B_0, B_1, B_2, B_n]
```

where `B_0, B_1, ..., B_n` have the same number of rows, but the different number of columns and `n` may be very large. I also have another 1d array `idx` with shape `(n+1,)`, and

```
B_i = B[:, idx[i]:idx[i+1]]
```

and `idx[-1]` (the last elements of `idx`) is the total number of columns of `B`.

I want to do same matrix operation for every `B_i`, for example:

```
B_i.T()@B_i
```

Or with another 2d array:

```
D = [[D_0], [D_1], ..., [D_n]]
```

with `D_0, D_1, ..., D_n` have the same number of columns which is equal to the number of rows of `B`, but the different number of rows, and

```
D_i = D[idx[i]:idx[i+1], :]
```

and I want to compute `D_i@B_i`.

So my question is how to implement it in python and avoid using the `for` loop?

The following is a example:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
# Prepare the test data
n = 1000000 # the number of small matrix 

idx = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.int)
idx[1:] = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
idx = np.cumsum(idx)

B = np.random.rand(3, idx[-1])

# Computation
start = timer()
C = []
for i in range(n):
    B_i = B[:, idx[i]:idx[i+1]]
    C_i = B_i.T@B_i
    C.append(C_i)
end = timer()
print('Total time:', end - start)
```

Comment: So you are thinking of `B` as a large list of 2d arrays.  But since the `B_i` all have same number of rows, they can also be thought of a subsets of the columns a single 2d array.  `B_i` is (3,n_i), so `C_i` is (n_i,n_i), a different size for each `i`.  So you can't collect those into one big array.  Unless you arrange the `B_i` on a 'diagonal' into a (3*n, idx[-1]) array.  A dot product with that might be the `C_i` on a 'diagonal'.  But that will be large with lots of 0s - suggesting a sparse matrix approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `map` and `lambda` function to finish this job, please see the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
# Prepare the test data
n = 1000000 # the number of small matrix 

idx = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.int)
idx[1:] = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
idx = np.cumsum(idx)

B = np.random.rand(3, idx[-1])
D = np.random.rand(idx[-1], 3)

BB = np.hsplit(B, idx[1:-1])
DD = np.vsplit(D, idx[1:-1])

CC = list(map(lambda x: x[0]@x[1], zip(DD, BB)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I add to your code:

```
print(B.shape)
print(idx)
print([x.shape for x in C])

Bnn = np.zeros((n, 3, idx[-1]))
for i in range(n):
    s = np.s_[idx[i]:idx[i+1]]
    Bnn[i,:,s] = B[:, s]
Bnn = Bnn.reshape(3*n,-1)
Cnn = Bnn.T @ Bnn
print(Bnn.shape, Cnn.shape)
print(Cnn.sum(), sum([x.sum() for x in C]))
```

and change `n=5`, I get

```
2115:~/mypy$ python3 stack46209231.py 
(3, 31)    # B shape
[ 0  9 17 18 25 31]
[(9, 9), (8, 8), (1, 1), (7, 7), (6, 6)]  # shapes of C elements
(15, 31) (31, 31)     # shapes of diagonalized B and C
197.407879357 197.407879357   # C sums from the 2 routes
```

So my idea of making a diagonalized version of `B`, and performing the dot product with that works.  For modest sized arrays that should be faster, though the iteration to create `Bnn` will take time, as will extracting the blocks from `Cnn`.

But `Bnn` and `Cnn` will get very large, and get bogged down with memory swaps, and eventually with memory errors.

---

With the `block_diag` function, turning your `B` into a sparse matrix is quite easy:

```
from scipy import sparse

Blist = [B[:, idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(n)]
Bs = sparse.block_diag(Blist, format='bsr')
print(repr(Bs))
Cs = Bs.T@Bs
print(repr(Cs))
print(Cs.sum())
```

and a sample run

```
2158:~/mypy$ python3 stack46209231.py 
(3, 20)
[ 0  1  5  9 17 20]
[(1, 1), (4, 4), (4, 4), (8, 8), (3, 3)]
(15, 20) (20, 20)
94.4190125992 94.4190125992
<15x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 60 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
<20x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 106 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

and shapes and checksums match.

For `n = 10000`, `Bnn` is too large for my memory.  The sparse `Bs` creation is slow, but the matrix multiplication is fast.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say this looks like some sort of FEM implementation, and for that BSR is the way to go.

Comment: @DanielF Yes, you are right. I am coding a FEM on the polygon mesh, so the shape of the stiffness matrix on every polygon cell may be different.

Comment: In a FEM stiffness matrix, the blocks (element matrices) overlap at shared nodes. Sparse matrices are commonly used for this.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, one must use sparse matrix in FEM. The code in my question is for the construction of each element stiffness matrix. After that, I will put it into a sparse matrix.

Comment: Years ago I struggled to improve the performance of a MATLAB stiffness matrix assembly.  FORTRAN code uses 3-4 levels of iteration -  elements, nodes, gauss pts, dof.  If you must iterate on one or more of those, it is best to do so on a small dimension like gauss pts (9).  The number of elements is large, and should not be iterated (if possible). Also take advantage of the `coo to csr` summing of duplicates.

Comment: @hpaulj, Yes, you are right. There is a Matlab FEM package named [iFEM](https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/programming.html), which does the thing what you are talking about. Now I am developing a Python FEM package [FEALPy](https://github.com/weihuayi/fealpy). I think the guass integration iteration also can be vectorized.